# How can I implement MergeSort with bound inclusive to exclusive?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying the implement the MergeSort algorithm in Java so that it takes it sorts an array from `A[start..end]`. I'm really struggling to implement it so that it doesn't include the last index passed in, in the merge. I'm trying to trace my code but keep getting confused.

Here is my code:

```java
public class MergeSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] list = new int[] { 3, 7, 5, 2, 9 };
      int[] result = mergeSort(list, 0, list.length);  
      System.out.print("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(" " + result[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("]");
   }

   public static int[] mergeSort(int[] list, int start, int end) {
      if (end - start < 2) {
         return list;
      } else {
         int mid = (start + end) / 2;
         mergeSort(list, start, mid);
         mergeSort(list, mid + 1, end);
         merge(list, start, mid, end);
         return list;
      }
   }

   public static void merge(int[] list, int start, int mid, int end) {
      int[] copy = new int[list.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         copy[i] = list[i];
      }
      int i = start;
      int k = start;
      int j = mid + 1;
      while (i <= mid && j <= end) {
         if (copy[i] <= copy[j]) {
            list[k] = copy[i];
            i++;
         } else {
            list[k] = copy[j];
            j++;
         }
         k++;
      }
      while (i <= mid) {
         list[k] = copy[i];
         i++;
         k++;
      }
      while (j < end) {
         list[k] = copy[j];
         j++;
         k++;
      } 
   }   
}
```

Comment: you are not supposed to remove the code from the question as it makes the answers inconsistent. The code has a few bugs, which I pointed to and helped correct. There is no problem with that, all programmers make errors, learning from others is the way to improve. Other readers will read your code and will or will not see the problems, it is a good exercise anyway. Reading code is **much more difficult** than writing code, so  try and see what corrections I suggested in the answer and what other changes I made.

Comment: Excluding the upper bound is not usually taught in programming schools, but it is a better approach and makes the code simpler and more generic. I wish everybody would teach `mergesort` this way.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `mergesort` with a slice defined with `start` included and `end` excluded is indeed a sensible approach as the calling sequence is simpler: `merge(array, 0, array.length)` and it allows for empty slices, which is necessary for empty arrays.

Your `mergesort` method has a bug: the right slice starts at `mid` and ends before `end`, hence the call should be `mergeSort(list, mid, end);`

There are problems in the `merge` method too:

- you should not duplicate the whole `list`, but just the slice from `start` to `end` (excluded). It is simpler if you merge into the temporary array and copy it back after merging. With this approach, you can stop the merge when the left part is exhausted as the remaining values from the right part are already in the proper place.
- you should use the `<` operator instead of `<=` when comparing the running index values to the upper boundaries that are excluded with this approach.

Here is a corrected version:

```java
public class MergeSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] list = new int[] { 3, 7, 5, 2, 9 };
      int[] result = mergeSort(list, 0, list.length);  
      System.out.print("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(" " + result[i]);
      }
      System.out.println(" ]");
   }

   public static int[] mergeSort(int[] list, int start, int end) {
      if (end - start < 2) {
         return list;
      } else {
         // compute the mid point:
         //  the left part spans from start included to mid excluded
         //  the right part spans from mid included to end excluded
         // avoid adding start and end to prevent overflow overflow for very large arrays
         int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
         mergeSort(list, start, mid);
         mergeSort(list, mid, end);
         merge(list, start, mid, end);
         return list;
      }
   }

   public static void merge(int[] list, int start, int mid, int end) {
      int[] temp = new int[end - start];
      int k = 0;     // index into the temporary array
      int i = start; // index into the left part, stop at mid
      int j = mid;   // index into the right part, stop at end
      // select from left or right slices and store into the temp array
      while (i < mid && j < end) {
         if (list[i] <= list[j]) {
            temp[k++] = list[i++];
         } else {
            temp[k++] = list[j++];
         }
      }
      // copy the remaining elements from the left part
      while (i < mid) {
         temp[k++] = list[i++];
      }
      // copy the sorted elements back to the original list
      for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
         list[start + i] = temp[i];
      }
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either call `mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);`

Or call a helper function let's say `F`. So for example you would call `F(list, 0, list.length);` Where the only thing `F` would do is it would call `mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);`.

That way you don't even touch `mergeSort` anymore. You just call `F`.

Edit:

```
public class MergeSort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] list = new int[] {3, 7, 5, 2, 9};
      int[] result = mergeSort(list, 0, list.length);  
      System.out.print("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(" " + result[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("]");
   }

   public static int[] mergeSort(int[] list, int start, int end) {
      return F(list, start, end - 1);
   }

   public static int[] F(int[] list, int start, int end) {
      if (end - start < 2) {
         return list;
      } else {
         int mid = (start + end) / 2;
         F(list, start, mid);
         F(list, mid + 1, end);
         merge(list, start, mid, end);
         return list;
      }
   }

   public static void merge(int[] list, int start, int mid, int end) {
      int[] copy = new int[list.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      copy[i] = list[i];
      }
      int i = start;
      int k = start;
      int j = mid + 1;
      while (i <= mid && j <= end) {
         if (copy[i] <= copy[j]) {
            list[k] = copy[i];
            i++;
         } else {
            list[k] = copy[j];
            j++;
         }
         k++;
      }
      while (i <= mid) {
         list[k] = copy[i];
         i++;
         k++;
      }
      while (j < end) {
         list[k] = copy[j];
         j++;
         k++;
      } 
   }   
}
```

Comment: Then try the helper function method that I mentioned. You can look at my edited answer for more details.

Comment: @MahmoodDarwish: your proposal defeats the OP's goal: *srpall* wants the slice to be defined as `start` included and `end` excluded, which not only makes sense, but allows for a very elegant implementation without any spurious +1 adjustments. I wish teachers would stop promoting the included/included code, it is counter productive and error prone.